# Simplifying $\beta_1$ estimate for a simple linear regression model

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-regression

For a simple linear regression model I am able to derive the normal equations and solve these to  to obtain the following-
$$\beta_0=\bar{Y}-\beta_1\bar{X}$$
$$\beta_1=\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$$

However in my text book and elsewhere online I see that $\beta_1$ is often (not always) simplified to 
$$\beta_1=\frac{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})Y_i}{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}.$$

How does one arrive at this simplification? It is not at all obvious to me why?

Comment: The simplification is wrong...

Comment: It is correct. Why don't you expand the numerator of the first expression?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum (X_i - \bar{X}) ( Y_i - \bar{Y}) &= \sum(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i - \sum(X_i - \bar{X})\bar{Y} \\
&= \sum(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i - \sum X_i \bar{Y} +\sum\bar{X}\bar{Y} \\
&= \sum(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i - n\bar{Y}\bar{X} +n\bar{Y}\bar{X}\\
&= \sum(X_i - \bar{X})Y_i.
\end{align}